# GooglePlaces doesn't work when using proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I use googlePlaces and google Map APIs in my android application, all work fine. When I enable Proguard, Google Map is working fine but Google Places doesn't work, It returns no result for all my search requests. After seeing the logs, I find out the part of code that doesn't work :

```
try {

        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
        request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
        if(types != null)
            request.getUrl().put("types", types);

        PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
        // Check log cat for places response status
        Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
        return list;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

This code returns null with the proguard version, and returns a result with the normal version.

I tried to keep all the classes that working with googlePlaces like this :

```
-keep public class com.example.android.mapexample.GooglePlaces
-keep public class com.example.android.mapexample.Place
-keep public class com.example.android.mapexample.PlaceDetails
-keep public class com.example.android.mapexample.PlacesList
```

But it doesn't work. :/ I don't know what is wrong.

proguard-google-api-client.txt http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=TAEQI

proguard-project.txt http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=HFbTF

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

Solved the issue after keeping Serializable classes wich use google map API

```
-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
     static final long serialVersionUID;
     private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
     !static !transient <fields>;
     !private <fields>;
     !private <methods>;
     private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
     private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
     java.lang.Object writeReplace();
     java.lang.Object readResolve();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly probably due to new versions, the suggested answer didn't work for me:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.15.0'
```

But this Proguard rule fixed it, at least for now:

```
-keep class com.google.maps.** { *; }
```

Reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174494519)